# Script tag in ASPX page is written partially (output stopped at random)

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I have an aspx page where I put a script tag with .net "if" and "else".
The problem is that the output gets cut at random points each time. Sometimes it's ok, sometimes I get cropped output.

The code itself (Simplified example):

```
<body id="body" runat="server">
<form id="form1" runat="server">some HTML
    <script type="text/javascript">
         window.addEvent('domready', function() { 
           var x = "nothing";
           <% if(someCondition){%>
           x = "2";
           <%} else {%>
           x = "3";
           <%}%>
          });
    </script>
</form>
</body>
```

The cropped output:

```
<body id="body" runat="server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">some HTML
        <script type="text/javascript">
             window.addEvent('domready', function() { 
               var x = "nothi
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
```

Does anybody have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would sugest it is throwing some kind of exception when it isn't working and not outputting the full error message.  Rather than doint it that way, use a Literal control and build up the script tag in the code behind.  That way you can debug and see what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that it happens only in production servers, and changes there are not easy. I was thinking more in the direction of faulty IIS configuration. I will do like you suggested, but it'll take two weeks or so until it goes to production... Thanks.

Comment: If it only happens on aproduction server, i would recomend trying to recreate the server hosting environment e.g. os version, web server & web app config etc on a vm and see if you can recreate the error there.